# Nesting IFs to run script on a condition

Tags: php

I have a script that checks to see if there are bad words before accepting a post. This only should happen for a post that is rated G for kids. I do know the rating, but the rating is not stored in the same table and when I tried this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['contribute']) && $row[0]['rating'] == "G")
```

Nothing works. If I do it without the rating it works.

So my question is, can I embed an If within and If instead? Something like this...

```
if ($row[0]['rating'] == "G"){

if (isset($_POST['contribute'])){

// Words not allowed
$disallowedWords = array(
    'swear1',
    'swear2',
);

}
}
```

Comment: You sure can. Not sure why your original isn't working, though: it looks valid to me.

Comment: the two versions are functionary equivalent.demo: http://ideone.com/CUfzyv

Comment: That's what I thought. But the contribute variable is from a form and the rating variable is from a separate sql query, so maybe they can't be lumped together in the same if

Comment: Perhaps because the SQL query that gets the rating happens farther down on the page? I didn't think that mattered though...

Comment: if the variable exist, there source is irrelevant, just echo them out to make sure that they are there

Comment: " farther down on the page?" the processing is linear. you can't check for a variable before it has been created

Comment: That was my issue. I needed to place the code after the SQL. I was thinking bc it was post data placement didn't matter, but it does for the variable.

Comment: I suggest you delete your post :)